# Can request handlers be used when writing C# AWS lambda functions?

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

I'm writing my first Lambda function and I was wondering if there was something akin to the request handlers that we get with MVC. I'd like to relegate all my auth code to a common location and run it on every request of every type made. Lack of documentation of request handlers suggests I'll probably be calling AuthUtility.Authorize() at the beginning of every function but I wanted to ask if there was a better solution.

Thanks!